Estimating variance of a Gaussian distribution from the mean of absolute values of first differences in a sequential sample
Edited Question:
This question is about estimating the variance (or $\text{SD}_0$) of a parent distribution from which a set of random independent samples is taken.  The samples are taken in sequence and the mean of absolute values of the first differences (between each pair of adjacent observations) is known, and so is the sample size, but nothing else.  The sequence is assumed stationary and there is no autocorrelation.
I assume that the parent distribution is Gaussian, or at least not too far from it.
My way of trying to figure it out is that it seems that the absolute first differences should have the Half-normal distribution constructed from an underlying Normal distribution with $\text{mean}=0$ and $\text{SD}=\sqrt{2}\cdot\text{SD}_0.$  Therefore the mean of this Half-normal distribution (mean_delta) should be
$$\sqrt{2}\cdot \text{SD}_0\cdot\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{\pi} = 2\cdot\text{SD}_0/\sqrt{\pi}.  $$
Therefore the $\text{SD}_0$ of the original distribution could be estimated as $\sqrt{\pi}\cdot \text{mean_delta}/2 \approx 1.128\cdot\text{mean_delta}.$
My question is: am I even on the right track?
Original Question:
The absolute difference of two random independent samples from a standard Normal distribution seems to be Half-normal.
What would be the $\text{SD}$ of it if the negative half of it was also present?  I've seen the $\sqrt{1-2/\pi}$ value but is that the $\text{SD}$ of the resultant Half-normal distribution or the $\text{SD}$ of the Normal distribution, right half of which being the Half-normal in question?

If $X$ and $Y$ are iid $N(0,1)$ then $X-Y \sim N(0,2)$ and so $|X-Y|$ has a half-normal distribution with $\sigma=\sqrt{2}$ $\Big($not to be confused with its standard deviation of $\sqrt{2-\frac4\pi}\Big)$.

@Henry, why does $| X -Y |$ imply that the $\sigma = \sqrt{2}$?

Could you please explain what you mean by "negative half ... present"?

@nwaldo The $\sigma$ scale parameter for the $|X-Y|$ half-normal distribution  is the same as the $\sigma$ parameter for the $X-Y$ normal distribution and is the square root of the variance of $X-Y$ which is $1+1=2$.

@whuber I guess the 'negative half...' doesn't make much sense - I was trying to start from the Half-normal distribution (without considering how it may have been constructed by folding the underlying Normal) and imagine how it would look like if I just add the 'missing' half.  But that would make the area under the curve equal to 2, so it wouldn't represent the PDF.

When you "add the missing half" of course you need to renormalize it to integrate to unity--and I hope it's obvious that you recover the original normal distribution.

Re the edit (which appears to have completely changed the question): If you don't know the parent distribution, there are no good solutions.  At best you can obtain a lower confidence limit.  The problem lies in the inherent systematic bias of using absolute differences rather than squared differences (which do measure the variance).  Are you assuming a Normal parent distribution or not?

@whuber Yes, I assume that the parent distribution is Gaussian, or at least not too far from it.

@whuber The question indeed evolved a bit (sorry) but it relates to the same problem of a real life measure of blood pressure variability and it's reasons and consequences.  The use of the mean of absolute first differences became common in literature.  Since you've mentioned it, how much better the RMSE (error being the first difference here) would have been if used instead, I wonder?

It is also interesting to consider what  would happen if one previous assumption was relaxed, and that the series of observations exhibited either a trend or wasn't stationary.  This seems possible given the context of the question - the uncertainty of the measurements includes the instrument/method errors as well as the possible real blood pressure variations on the scale of minutes.  I'm not really asking how to deal with it, but rather looking for ideas as to how the use of absolute first difference vs. the variance of observations regardless of sequence would perform to show dispersion..

The problem is that the possibility of serial correlation--and there always is some, because you are averaging first differences--means you can't infer anything about the variability of your estimate.

I'm starting not to see the forest for the trees....:-) There is a process: a time series of a certain kind of blood pressure (BP) that varies on different time scales.  How it varies makes a difference and has consequences.  The only way to estimate how it varies is to measure it periodically.  The instruments and the method employed report uncertain values.  As the blood pressure may vary during and between measurements, this adds to uncertainty.  The question is how far from the 'true' BP those measured estimates could be, and how likely at that.  There are not that many ways to do it....

There are a huge number of ways to do that and the answers can vary tremendously.  The basic problem is that retaining only the mean absolute difference has destroyed almost all information about the variance.

But given that the parent distribution is indeed Gaussian and that the sequence of samples are iid, wouldn't the mean of absolute differences (which depends on variance of the parent distribution) reflect the parent variance about as well as other point measures of dispersion such as sample SD?

I realize you stated these are "random samples," but the context you describe in comments suggests they are not anywhere near iid: your language hints they are repeated measures.  That, and the lack of information about how many samples you have, are what suggested to me the hopelessness of pursuing this question without additional information or assumptions.

@whuber, The way I treat the series of measurements of an unknown quantity is that the quantity is constant but the instrument and the method introduce a random noise around it (possibly symmetric if not Gaussian) and it's the variance of this noise that it's in question.  So each reading constitutes an observation affected by this noise and I think can be seen as iid.  The sample sizes are in teens at a few different levels of the quantity being measured and the distribution of the 'noise' seems independent of the value of the quantity being measured.

Okay, that's fine, but it's not what one would expect from your data collection procedure. If you wish to estimate the variance of the noise (a) you would do so in a way that doesn't depend on the sequence of observations and regardless (b) you would use a statistic, such as squared differences, that enable you to estimate the variance directly and without bias. Under your assumptions what you have are $n-1$ serially correlated observations of a Normal variable of twice the original variance and correlation coefficient $-1/2.$ Its mean and $n$ will suffice to estimate the variance.

@whuber: OK, then how would you estimate this parent distribution's variance?  Would what I posited in the original question agree with your ideas?
